# AVPlayer and AVAssetReader produce artifacts with odd-width ProRes422 video

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, video-processing, quicktime

While working on the video editing app I (and a few users on different machines) noticed something unusual about QuickTime files of odd-width encoded with ProRes422 codec. When opening in the standard `AVPlayer` they contain an artifact (small pink line) on the right edge. The same artifact is present in `CMSampleBuffer` when reading the file using standard `AVAssetReader`. This doesn't happen with even-width videos or when using ProRes4444 encoder. Here's what it looks like.

[image]

I tried opening both videos in other apps (Elmedia Player, Camera Bag Pro, VLC) and every non-Apple app that I tested renders the odd-width video with the artifact. The standard QuickTime Player doesn't show the artifact, neither does Safari when drag-and-dropping the file there. Other Apple apps that I tried (Photos, Preview, Apple TV) render it without the pink line too.

I'd really like to know why this happens and if ProRes422 requires some special handling how can the artifact can be avoided:

1. in `CMSampleBuffer` when reading the video with `AVAssetReader`;
2. and when playing the video in standard `AVPlayer` control.

Even- and odd-width videos from the above screenshot can be produced with the following code that runs in a macOS Xcode Playground:

```
// Produce two QuickTime MOV (ProRes422) files of odd and even width. Odd one will contain
// a pink line artifact on the right edge in some players. Even one won't. Why?

import AVFoundation
import CoreImage
import CoreMedia

let sizeEven = CGSize(width: 500, height: 250)
let sizeOdd = CGSize(width: 501, height: 250)
let urlEven = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/ianbytchek/Downloads/blue-even.mov")
let urlOdd = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/ianbytchek/Downloads/blue-odd.mov")

func createQuickTime(url: URL, size: CGSize) {
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
    let outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.proRes422, AVVideoWidthKey: size.width, AVVideoHeightKey: size.height] as [String: Any]
    let input = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: outputSettings)
    let writer = AVAssetWriter(url: url, fileType: .mov, inputs: [input])

    precondition(writer.startWriting())
    writer.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)

    for i in 0 ..< 10 {
        while !input.isReadyForMoreMediaData { Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1 / 100) }
        let image = CIImage.blue.cropped(to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        let buffer = CMSampleBuffer.create(size: size, image: image, timestamp: Double(i) / 10)
        precondition(input.append(buffer))
    }

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    input.markAsFinished()
    writer.finishWriting(completionHandler: { semaphore.signal() })
    semaphore.wait()
}

createQuickTime(url: urlOdd, size: sizeOdd)
createQuickTime(url: urlEven, size: sizeEven)

extension AVAssetWriter {
    convenience init(url: URL, fileType: AVFileType, inputs: [AVAssetWriterInput]) {
        try! self.init(url: url, fileType: fileType)
        inputs.forEach({ precondition(self.canAdd($0)); self.add($0) })
    }
}
extension CMSampleBuffer {
    static func create(imageBuffer: CVImageBuffer, sampleTiming: CMSampleTimingInfo) -> CMSampleBuffer {
        let formatDescription = CMVideoFormatDescription.create(imageBuffer: imageBuffer)
        var sampleTiming = sampleTiming
        var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?
        CMSampleBufferCreateReadyWithImageBuffer(allocator: nil, imageBuffer: imageBuffer, formatDescription: formatDescription, sampleTiming: &sampleTiming, sampleBufferOut: &sampleBuffer)
        return sampleBuffer!
    }
    static func create(imageBuffer: CVImageBuffer, timestamp: Double) -> CMSampleBuffer {
        let scale = CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let presentationTimestamp = CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(timestamp * Double(scale)), timescale: scale)
        let sampleTiming = CMSampleTimingInfo(duration: CMTime.invalid, presentationTimeStamp: presentationTimestamp, decodeTimeStamp: CMTime.invalid)
        return self.create(imageBuffer: imageBuffer, sampleTiming: sampleTiming)
    }
    static func create(size: CGSize, image: CIImage, timestamp: Double) -> CMSampleBuffer {
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
        let pixelBuffer = CVPixelBuffer.create(size: size, pixelFormat: kCMPixelFormat_32ARGB, attributes: [kCVImageBufferCGColorSpaceKey: colorSpace])
        CIContext().render(image, to: pixelBuffer, bounds: image.extent, colorSpace: colorSpace)
        return self.create(imageBuffer: pixelBuffer, timestamp: timestamp)
    }
}
extension CMVideoFormatDescription {
    static func create(imageBuffer: CVImageBuffer) -> CMVideoFormatDescription {
        var formatDescription: CMVideoFormatDescription?
        CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(allocator: nil, imageBuffer: imageBuffer, formatDescriptionOut: &formatDescription)
        return formatDescription!
    }
}
extension CVPixelBuffer {
    static func create(size: CGSize, pixelFormat: OSType? = nil, attributes: [CFString: Any]? = nil) -> CVPixelBuffer {
        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
        CVPixelBufferCreate(nil, Int(size.width), Int(size.height), pixelFormat ?? kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attributes as CFDictionary?, &pixelBuffer)
        return pixelBuffer!
    }
}
```